# Is there a vim equivalent to bash's '!$'?

Tags: bash, vim, sh

I often find myself doing something like this while developing:

```
:e <file>
:vsplit <the_same_file>  "reopen/re-edit with a vertical split
```

As a few responders have pointed out, there's a much better way to do this: `:vs<CR>`. Suppose for a moment there weren't.

If I were opening files in my shell, I'd use the `!$` history expansion to capture the last argument of the previous command, like this:

```
$ echo "Hello" "stackoverflow"
Hello stackoverflow
$ echo "I'm posting on !$"
I'm posting on stackoverflow
```

This expansion, and the [many others like it,](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#History-Interaction) utterly redefined the way I used the command line. Are there equivalents in vim? I know `%` aliases the current file. What about past-command arguments?

Comment: I do not know of any direct equivalences to bash's `!$`. However you may be interested in using `q:` which brings up the command line window. The command line window shows history of your last commands and lets the user use normal vim commands to make edits to the command. See `:h cmdwin` for more information.

Comment: I don't think vim command line has the same feature set of bash's.  your `!$` could be shorter in bash: `<alt-.>`. also if you want to achieve the operation at the beginning of your question in vim, after you open the file with `:e file`, you can press `<c-w>v` or `<c-w><c-v>` the latter is easier to press.

Comment: You can use `:e %` and `:e #` to (re)edit the current file and the previous file — would that help?

Comment: @Kent: Those get me through this specific case, and both of your shortcuts are useful. However I'm more interested in expansions generally. I've edited the question accordingly.

Comment: No, it's not fairly easy to imagine those situations. Since your example is both very trivial and inaccurate (`:vs<CR>`), maybe you could help us with actual examples where what you ask would be useful?

Comment: @romainl: After giving it some thought, I removed the line about it being easy to think of examples. I can construct quite a few, but none that don't have other means to do the same thing. In the end, I'm not trying to claim vim *should* have this ability. I simply want to know if it does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know Vim does not have history expansion.

The natural thing to do then is to use the tools Vim gives us on the command line. And we have options!

- `<Up>` arrow filtering
- Command-line editing commands

  - `CTRL-W` to delete a word backwards
  - `<Left>` and `<Right>` to move around, `CTRL-B` and `CTRL-E` to move to start/end of line
- Use the **command-line window `q:`** (or `CTRL-F` when already on the command line) **for ultimate history editing power**
- *Find idiomatic alternative solutions in the Vim spirit for the specific problem at hand*

  - Automatically expanded tokens like `%` and `#` are a good example

---

**However,** if you really want Bash-style history expansion you can hack something together with command-line `<expr>` abbreviations fairly easily (at least for the simpler cases).

The history expansion items I use most often (frankly not very often):

- `!!`, the most recent command line
- `!-2`, the second most recent command line
- `!*`, all arguments but the first of the previous command line
- `!$`, the last argument of the previous command line

Here's how you can implement them as expression abbreviations:

```
cnoreabbr <expr> !!  getcmdtype() == ':' ? @: : '!*'
cnoreabbr <expr> !-2 getcmdtype() == ':' ? histget(':', -2) : '!-2'
cnoreabbr <expr> !*  getcmdtype() == ':' ? join(split(@:,'\s\+')[1:], ' ') : '!*'
cnoreabbr <expr> !$  getcmdtype() == ':' ? split(@:,'\s\+')[-1] : '!$'
```

And here's how your example would work in Vim:

```
:echo "Hello Stackoverflow"
Hello Stackoverflow
:echo "I'm posting on !$<Enter>
I'm posting on Stackoverflow
```

Of course, use functions for more complex expressions if you really decide to go down this route.

Comment: I was thinking you could do something list this. However I didn't want to post it as a answer Mostly because the split doesn't work to well with strings or functions.

Comment: In your example I would have expected `"Hello Stackoverflow"` to be replaced as the last argument. Which obviously can't happen because you're splitting on whitespace.

Comment: It works only in some simple cases. That's why I said "use functions". But I don't think it is reasonable (or even doable) to extract the `@:` and try to parse the command line, just stick with normal command-line editing.

Comment: Its doable. You just need to write a full pushdown automata to do the parsing. (Or figure out a way for python to do it)

Comment: So after think about this a bit longer. This isn't reasonable at all.  You just need to write a complete vim script parser inside vim script. Its not reasonable because there are so many corner cases that need to be considered. You also need to consider what does it mean to be the last argument? Consider an `:exec` command that uses string concatenation. Is the argument everything after exec? or just the last string being concatenated? I still feel this is doable but I'm not sure its reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

Using `:vsp` with no arguments splits the current window.

Not exactly what you're asking for, but I often use `%` which is the current filename:

```
:e some_file
:vsp %
```

See `:help cmdline-special`

Comment: That sets me for this specific case, but it's also just the first case I could think of when I wanted to repeat a previous argument or command with an expansion. Happen to know of any expansions?

Answer (score 0):

The outstanding [best of VIM tips](http://zzapper.co.uk/vimtips.html) pointed out one specific area where history repetition works, namely in substitutions:

```
" Summary of editing repeats [N]
.      last edit (magic dot)
:&     last substitute
:%&    last substitute every line
:%&gic last substitute every line confirm
g%     normal mode repeat last substitute
g&     last substitute on all lines
@@     last recording
@:     last command-mode command
:!!    last :! command
:~     last substitute
:help repeating
```